# COUNTIF with variables

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to get my information from three columns:

```
column A has the names of 200 different people.
column B has 24 different locations.
column C has every date of the year.
```

for an equation that can tell me how often `john` was at the `north gate` on `sept 1st`, or how often `mary` was at the `lay-down` on `oct 29`. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please try `=COUNTIFS(A:A,E1,B:B,F1,C:C,G1)` where your variables are in E1 (john), F1 (north gate) and G1 (sept 1st).